# strongloop: how to change service ID of application deployed on process manager?

Tags: strongloop

StrongLoop Arc "sees" only the service associated to the ID = 1 on a process manager (PM). It looks like PM doesn't "free" the service IDs once you remove service, so I am not able to make a second service visible to Arc, even after I have removed the first one. Do you know how to modify the ID of a service? or to completely "clean up" the configuration of process manager, so that it can start again from 1 for a new deployment?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to remove the config. If this is using the "production" deployment described on strong-pm.io then you'll do something like:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/strong-pm/* && sudo service strong-pm restart
```

The specific file to remove is `strong-pm.json`, if you prefer a more precise approach.

Comment: I think there's a syntax error in that restart.. should be `sudo service strong-pm restart`

Comment: Depends on the distribution as to whether `restart` has been surfaced as a shell command or not. Whatever I was regularly using at the time had it and I must have gotten used to it. `service` is definitely more portable across Linux distros, though.